# Facebook like popup window for custom oAuth

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I want to show a popup window like facebook login and on a successful login i want to close that popup window and redirect to original one.

i am using my custom oAuth but i want to use it like a Facebook login

i am using sencha touch and when i open window using `window.open` a new full screen window opens up and on a successfully login the redirect page is opening in the new popup window only.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like a floating container with an iframe

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.oAuthContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    config: {
        centered: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
        hideOnMaskTap: false,
        modal: true,
        html: '<iframe src="https://myOAuthLoginService onLoad="MyApp.app.getController("MyController").myMethodToHandleAniFrameRedirect(this);"></iframe>"',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'spacer'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                handler: function(button, event) {
                    button.up("container").hide({type: 'fade', out: true});
                },
                iconCls: 'delete'
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

Then all you would have to do is create a controller called MyController with a method called myMethodToHandleAniFrameRedirect(iframe) to handle the iframe redirect upon successful oauth login. You can grab the url from the iframe object in the method to make sure that authentication was successful.

Comment: i tried ur approach but still the page is getting redirected in iframe itself rather then parent window